# WebAPI routing: Combining Attributes and HttpConfiguration settings

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to have a `GET` and a `POST` for the same route:

I've registered the following:

```
  config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "MyGetMethod",
                routeTemplate: "api/v1/users/{user}",
                defaults: new
                              {
                                  controller = "Users",
                                  action = "MyGetMethod"
                              },
                constraints: null,
                handler: HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(
                    new HttpControllerDispatcher(config),
                    routeHandlerFactory.Create()));

  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "MySetMethod",
                routeTemplate: "api/v1/users/{user}",
                defaults: new
                              {
                                  controller = "Users",
                                  action = "MySetMethod"
                              },
                constraints: null,
                handler: HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(
                    new HttpControllerDispatcher(config),
                    routeHandlerFactory.Create()));
```

My `UsersController.cs`  contains:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage MySetMethod(string user)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented);
    }


 [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage MyGetMethod(string user)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented);
    }
```

This doesn't work. 
The `GET` works fine, but when I use `POST` the WebAPI still redirects to the `GET` method and I get the error:

> "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method
>   'POST'."

If I comment out the registration of the `GET` method, then the `POST` works fine.

Is it because I'm using a combination between Attributes `[HttpPost]`, `[HttpGet]` on the Controller methods instead of marking them as `constraints`?

How can I have a `GET` and `POST` on the same route?

Comment: What about using one method with check `if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "POST")`?

Answer (score 0):

if you use this will work

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "DefaultApi",
      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
      defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
 );
```

Comment: i'm was using    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();, sorry I forgot to add it. Edited the question. Doesn't work

Comment: please check this http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api no need of separate Post and get Routemap and use routeMap attribute in your Controller

Answer (score 0):

You only need to define **one** `HttpRoute` for that, please try this:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "UserController",
                routeTemplate: "api/v1/users/{user}",
                defaults: new { user= RouteParameter.Optional }
                handler: HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(
                    new HttpControllerDispatcher(config),
                    routeHandlerFactory.Create()));
```

If this still doesn't work, please try the same code but change the `routeTemplate` to:

```
routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{user}"
```

And invoke the web method using a post to

```
https://YourServer/YourVirtualDirectory/api/v1/Users/myUser
```

Comment: I tried like this as well, still the same result :(.. If I move the HttpPost and HttpGet attributes from the controller methods and put them as constraints it works fine. 
But why can't I use the attributes?

Comment: Do you have the option to use AttributeRouting instead of convention based routing? I would highly recommend that. If yes, I will post you the answer.

Comment: You also have a type in the second parameter (HttRequestMessage) is missing a 'p'

Comment: can't use attribute routing

Comment: edited the question based on your comment, removed HttpRequestMessage